# FLUTTER I can't import image to google sheets

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets

I am saving data to google sheets with a form. It was working fine before the upload or take photo buttons. I want to take or upload a photo and export the photo data to google sheets. But it is not sending the data. Why? I also get an error like this **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: GSheetsException: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets. googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:655911674'.**

[image]

Comment: You are crossing quota limit with continuous API hit.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Comment: I guess it's about decode and encode. So, can't I solve this over-limit situation in another way?

Comment: "Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell." its same issue ?

Comment: Yeah you are converting image to Base64 for upload I think so hence it is bro-king. You can compress the image or either allowed 1MB image for upload. I think so.

Comment: How to do the compress?

Comment: Check for compression code or use library.